# Homology group $H_1(G;\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space?

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am reading a paper which is asking me to view the homology group $H_1(G;\mathbb{R})$ of a (presentation of a) group as a vector space. Now, my knowledge of homology is basically non-existent, but I do know that $H_1(G;\mathbb{R})$ "is" the abelianisation of $G$.

From the context of the paper the following seems reasonable. However, having searched around a bit I am having trouble verifying it. So I thought that I would ask here.

> Is the following true:
>
> The homology group $H_1(G;\mathbb{R})$ is the real vector space consisting of maps $\phi: G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (possibly also $\phi$ has finite support).

But I cannot think how this relates to the abelianisation definition. (And also I am pretty sure that these maps do not form a vector space!)

Comment: Homology with coefficients in R is not the abelianization, actually.

Comment: Before doing anything, ypu should consider the question of whether those maps do or do not form a vector space. It is quite a basic matter of good ol' linear algebra, which you should have a firm grasp before even thinking about the homology of anything!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez My problem was not so much with linearity, but rather I (for some reason) thought that a vector space could not be infinite-dimensional (it should have dimension $|G|$, but in my case $G$ is an infinite group). However, I have refreshed my memory of the definition and I see that bases do not matter...But still - without finite support, there *is no basis* (unless, again, I am missing something).

Comment: @user1729: every vector space has a basis assuming the axiom of choice. If you don't assume the axiom of choice, then yes, sometimes you can construct vector spaces without bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $H_1(G, \mathbb{Z})$ that's the abelianization of $G$. $H_1(G, \mathbb{R})$ is the tensor product of the abelianization of $G$ with $\mathbb{R}$, which is in particular a real vector space. It is much smaller than what you said.

Comment: In what way is it "much smaller"? Is it the maps with finite support? Also, what is the ring we are tensoring over? Just $\mathbb{Z}$? (Because you can view $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but clearly the abelinisation is not an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space for $G$ finitely generated.)

Comment: @user1729 see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94383/first-group-homology-with-general-coefficients

Comment: @user1729: for one thing, it can be finite-dimensional even if $G$ is infinite. Note also that your construction makes no use of the group structure of $G$. And yes.

Comment: Surely my construction makes no more or less use of the group structure of $G$ than this one (I am assuming $G$ is finitely generated) because a map to $\mathbb{R}$ encodes, in a certain sense, the abelinisation, so the space of all such maps is dependent on the abelinisation, while the tensor product is simply the abelinisation with $\mathbb{R}$. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @user1729: when you say "maps" do you mean homomorphisms of groups or maps of sets? If the former, this is $H^1(G, \mathbb{R})$. If the latter, this makes no use of the group structure.

Comment: I meant homomorphisms. Okay, that is interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @user1729: it was very unclear that you meant homomorphisms because "finite support" is a very strange condition on a homomorphism of groups. For example, it implies that the image of the homomorphism must be torsion...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Your right - when I was originally forming the question I only meant homomorphism. Somewhere along the way, I drifted to meaning maps (possibly with finite support, I had group algebras in mind for some reason). So it was unclear because, well, I was unclear!